# Prepopulate sqlite database with ionic application

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, sqlite

I am trying to implement following tutorial but with no luck so far.

I don't know what I am doing wrong I followed the exact same mentioned steps given [here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/deploy-ionic-framework-app-pre-filled-sqlite-db/), except for the `populated.db` I am using `xyz.sqlite`.

Also please tell me how can i get file in .db extention from mysql database through phpmyadmin

Comment: I can give you a  cordova / Phonegap example with sqlite ?

Comment: Please show me your code .

Comment: i think its better to use web service to connect with mysql

Comment: Are you simply wanting to view the contents of your sql lite database? or is it failing to create the database?

Comment: @HassanALi I am trying to deploy following tutorial 
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/deploy-ionic-framework-app-pre-filled-sqlite-db/

Comment: @Turv I am trying to package my apk file with prepopulated sqlite database.

Comment: you cannot import .db extention  from mysql .

Comment: @HassanALi That defines one thing. I found a way using sqlitebrowser to prepare a ready sqlite database. I just want to put it with my app

Comment: You have to syn data while installation of application .